# Ошибка при коммите в репозиторий (gpg failed to sign the data)

Tags: git, github, git-commit, gpg

Моя система: Arch Linux x64.

Коммиты делаю через JetBrains Rider, но думаю не суть важно (в настройках, GPG ключи настроены правильно).

При попытке коммита, вылетают такие ошибки:

```
error: gpg failed to sign the data
fatal: failed to write commit object
```

Чекнул вопросы на англоязычном Stackoverflow, перепробовал менять значения git переменных, переустанавливать gpg, ставить в переменные gpg и gpg2, изменять ключ в переменной гита, не помогло.
Судя по всему недавно вышла новая версия GPG, в которой ключ стал отображаться значительно более длинным чем раньше (раньше требовалось вписать 8 символов).
И да, я пробовал устанавливать в переменную, первые 8 символов этого ключа, не помогло.
Хотя челикам с форума помогло, хз.

Обновлено: Я брал ID ключа с гитхаба, предварительно импортировав ключ на него. В Rider установил правильный ключ в разделе Git. Проверил конфиги гита, там всё правильно, попробовал что-то зашифровать этим же ключом, всё работает.

Answer (score 0):

Я удалил файл ~/.gitconfig, попытался закоммитить, спросило e-mail и ник на гитхабе. Затем я установил значение commit.gpgsign в значение true, и без указания ключа, всё закоммитилось.